# WSO2 APIM Use Active Directory log in

Tags: active-directory, wso2-api-manager

Is it possible to configure the WSO2 APIM to use the current, on-prem, AD login, without requiring the user to enter the log in details again?

Think about the following scenario:

Working in a local, closed network, with AD DC on prem.
My SPA application accesses the API gateway. The user has already logged in using  AD when he turned on his PC.

How can I make the APIM use the same login data?